# get Rails3 app name in a template that generates a rails app?

Tags: templates, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a template that generates a rails app. The problem is that in my template scenario I substitute some files, like environment.rb, that need to know rails app name to run things like `AppName::Application.initialize!`. I could get the app name from the command line arguments, but that's not always possible, since a user could do that: `rails new ./` and the app name would be the name of the current dir then, but I would get nothing from the argument list.

So I'd like to know a certain way of getting a Rails app name in a template scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use app_name inside your generator file.

Lots of documentations here
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/classes/Rails/Generators/AppGenerator.html#method-i-app_name

and it changed to application_name in rails 4

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/NamedBase.html#method-i-application_name

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `app_name` attribute (as George Yacoub suggests).